# calling more than one service endpoint from DSS in ESB and constructing the Response XML in ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

whenever I make a call to getperson(id) from ESB with id as the query parameter;
I should get the following response

```
<person>
    <id\>
    <name\>
    <type\>
    <address>
        <street\>
        <apt\>
        <city\>
        <state\>
        <zipcode\>
    </address>
    <image>
        <id\>
        <description\>
        <title\>
    </image>
<person>
```

I have 3 services in DSS
services in DSS:

1. person_service

Response:

```
    <person>
        <id\>
        <name\>
        <type\>
        <addressid\>
        <imageid\>
    </person>
```

1. address_service

Response:

```
            <address>
        <street\>
        <apt\>
        <city\>
        <state\>
        <zipcode\>
    </address>
```

1. image_service

Response:

```
     <image>
        <id>
        <description>
        <title>
    </image>
```

I am trying to add a resource in ESB. how can I group the response of multiple DSS services into one XML as show in the above.

ESB version: 4.6.0
DSS version: 4.0.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this using service chaining and aggregator mediator. First make request to  person_service and get response, then use service chaining mechanism to send a request to address_service and so on. Then use aggregator mediator to combine the responses.

For service chaining refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Service+Chaining and for aggregator mediator refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/IntegrationPatterns/Aggregator

Comment: Thank you Ragavan, I was able to deploy the services in the Application Server.  But in the ESB we need to create an API with resources.  Sample doesn't illustrate about using the APIs.

Comment: Create Proxy services that are fronting the services you have hosted on the Application server. In the same documentation you can find the way to create proxy services.

Comment: I create two Pass Through Proxies with target endpoint as URL. But, how can I use them in API's when adding a resource to an API. Thanks Ragavan for your time